# php curl get angular page

Tags: php, angular, curl

I'd like to get an Angular page html source code with PHP Curl, but the full page body doesn't shown in the response only contains the Angular .js scripts which regenerate it:

```
<script src="runtime-es2015.7c3c0d8628bf61d47697.js" type="module"></script><script src="runtime-es5.7c3c0d8628bf61d47697.js" nomodule defer></script><script src="polyfills-es5.c658524be0ce21b2640d.js" nomodule defer></script><script src="polyfills-es2015.55cf3ea0002fe865bc15.js" type="module"></script><script src="scripts.7e3c12780cbda2cc3f17.js" defer></script><script src="main-es2015.12ca3e9e45aa1bc0bd92.js" type="module"></script><script src="main-es5.12ca3e9e45aa1bc0bd92.js" nomodule defer></script>
```

Any solutions to get the full html page body with PHP?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Scrape web page data generated by javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12630891/scrape-web-page-data-generated-by-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

Do you need the webpage HTML files, or the Angular project file type called templates ".html" extension?

[Angular html template files are compiled into JavaScript bundles you see during the build process](https://angular.io/guide/architecture-components). There is no way to get the template files from these angular javascript files.

The way angular works is that the Angular "Build" engine complies the .ts and .html files into special generator classes in js files and the angular "Runtime" engine uses them to create and modify the DOM.

In order to get the final HTML files, you need a browser to render the application.

Other solution is to serve the project code files on a static webserver to access the html templates.

Comment: the coment by CBroe shows a possible solution for scraping the build application.