# Wait for js to load before scraping

Tags: javascript, php, share-open-graph

I have a script that makes a iframe of an external url and it will also copy og tags using PHP scraper extension and insert the og tags to the frame page. Now the problem is the external site uses javascript to populate their og tags so my script isn't scraping the correct og tags since it doesn't scrape with javascript executed. How can I fix this?

```
<?php

define( 'DELAY', '0' ); // delay to redirect
yourls_add_action( 'pre_redirect', 'og_scraper' );
    


function og_scraper( $args ) {

        $url =  $args[0];
        $parsed_url = parse_url($url);
        
        require '/var/www/fantasticpix.com/htdocs/pixiviz/dist/artworks/includes/vendor/autoload.php';

        
            
        $web = new \spekulatius\phpscraper();

        $web->go($url);

        $data = $web->openGraph;
        $description = $web->openGraph['og:description'];
        if(empty($description)) 
        {
            $meta = get_meta_tags($url);
            $description = $meta['description'];
        }

        $description = $web->openGraph['og:title'];
        if(empty($title)) 
        {
            $page = file_get_contents($url);
            $title = preg_match('/<title[^>]*>(.*?)<\/title>/ims', $page, $match) ? $match[1] : null;    
        }

        $image = $web->openGraph['og:image'];
        if(substr($image, 0, 4) != "http" || substr($web->openGraph['og:image'], 0, 5) != "https") $image = $parsed_url['scheme'] . "://" . $parsed_url['host'] . $web->openGraph['og:image'];
    ?>
    <html>
        <head>
            <?php
                echo '<meta property="og:title" content="' . $title . '" />
                <meta property="og:type" content="' . $web->openGraph['og:type'] . '" />
                <meta property="og:url" content="' . $web->openGraph['og:location'] . '" />
                <meta property="og:image" content="' .  $image . '" />
                <meta property="og:site_name" content="' . $web->openGraph['og:site_name'] . '" />
                <meta property="og:description" content="' . $description . '" />';
            ?>
            
        </head>
<body><iframe id="yourls-frame" frameborder="0" noresize="noresize" src="<?php echo $url; ?>" name="yourlsFrame" style="position:fixed; top:0; left:0; bottom:0; right:0; width:100%; height:100%; border:none; margin:0; padding:0; overflow:hidden; z-index:999999;"></iframe></body>
    </html>
    <?php
    die();
    
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Scrape web page data generated by javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12630891/scrape-web-page-data-generated-by-javascript)

Comment: the site is doing it wrong, none of the bots like twitter or FB will wait for the tags to be populated by js